# AspNet core does not able to read FromQuery Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my .net core project I would like to implement query parameter and ignore body requests. But I am getting exception.

```
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "A non-empty request body is required."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "0HLUKJ3DJF87M:00000001"
}
```

My HttpPost method looks like

```
    [HttpPost]

    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateBillingInfo(BillingInfo billingInfoCreateDto, 
     [FromQuery]int projectId)
    {
        var role = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
        if (role != "admin")
        {
            return BadRequest("Available only for admin");
        }
        billingInfoCreateDto.Ram = await _context.VirtualMachines.Where(x => x.Project.Id == 
        projectId)
            .SumAsync(x => x.Ram);
        billingInfoCreateDto.DiskSize = await _context.VirtualMachines.Where(x => 
        x.Project.Id == projectId)
            .SumAsync(x => x.DiskSize);
        billingInfoCreateDto.Cpu = (short) await _context.VirtualMachines.Where(x => 
       x.Project.Id == projectId)
            .SumAsync(x => x.CPU); 
        billingInfoCreateDto.BeginApply = DateTime.Now.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay);
        billingInfoCreateDto.BeginApply = DateTime.Now.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerHour);
        billingInfoCreateDto.EndApply = billingInfoCreateDto.BeginApply.Value.AddHours(1);
        billingInfoCreateDto.ProjectId = projectId; // I am assigning query params here
        billingInfoCreateDto.Project = await _context.Projects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id 
   == billingInfoCreateDto.ProjectId);

        await _context.BillingInfos.AddAsync(billingInfoCreateDto);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return StatusCode(201);
    }
```

As I have navigation properties Project and ProjectId I need both of them.
How to assign query params to my linq query.Trying this in postman

```
http://localhost:5000/api/billinginfo?projectId=59
```

Comment: you model binding validations are giving the error via the `Required` attributes being used in the model class. Either you have to get rid of them (not a good practice), or you have to send the post request with a valid JSON data. Looks like you are trying to invoke the API to get some data, please review and add more context around the question.

Comment: That is true it is required and I know exception. But is it possible to read data from uri and put data to my query.all datas are automatically filling I just need projectId and I would like implement to read form uri not from body, if I put projectid as json it works as well

Comment: The error you've shown us has "A non-empty request body is required.". What is the body of the request you're posting, I guess it's probably empty? The error doesn't have anything to do with `projectId` and is instead talking about `billingInfoCreateDto`

Comment: @phuzi only empty field is projectId which I would like to get from uri

Comment: What's the purpose of passing `billingInfoCreateDto` into `CreateBillingInfo`? Do you expect its properties to be read from the request? Given how you use it, it seems you should _not_ take that in as a parameter and just create an instance inside of the `CreateBillingInfo` action.

Comment: @KirkLarkin it is properties which requires BillingInfo class and I created DTO version and passed params to them, in code everything is fine except projectId, if I put as body param as json of course it will work, but I need get projectId from uri and pass as projecCreationDto.ProejctId

Answer (score 0):

The following example code works. I have used the `"{projectId}"` in the HttpPost attribute and i am using that value inside controller, you can try to replace the order of the arguments and also try to add the route template and try.

```
    [HttpPost("{projectId}")]
    public DummyModel Post(String projectId,[FromBody]DummyModel model) {
        model.Id += projectId;
        return model;
    }
```

To invoke the above from `postman` tool, import the below given curl script into postman and test.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/wonderfulapi/123' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
    "id":"the-awesome-id"
}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not worked for me I got same exception. Tried add also FromRoute to projectId but it does not worked

Comment: I have posted the postman curl script, can you try like this from your postman and share the update.

Comment: what version of dotnet core are you using?

Comment: I am using .net core 2.2